# How to get the latest and complete com component code for windows?

Tags: c++, go, gcc, visual-c++, mingw

I hope to use windows COM components in GO, such as IFileDialog, IFileSaveDialog, IFileOpenDialog.

I have tried the following ways:

1. Use the vc++ compiler to compile the code and generate the .lib static library file. However, because GO uses the GCC compiler as a call bridge for the C language, and the .lib file generated by the VC++ compiler, GCC cannot be linked. fail.
2. Use the vc++ compiler to generate .dll files, and dynamically load the .dll files through the LoadLibray and GetProcAddress functions in `windows.h`. fail. The `syscall.LoadLibray` and `syscall.GetProcAddress` functions of the GO language have the same result. They run well for the .dll files generated by the GCC compiler, but they all fail for the .dll files generated by the VC++ compiler.
3. Use the GCC compiler to compile the code, because MinGW lacks the latest Windows com SDK, such as IID_IFileOpenDialog. fail.

Comment: Did you try looking at existing projects that use COM from Go successfully? E.g. this one: https://github.com/go-adsi/adsi

Comment: There is also this link for `go`: https://github.com/harry1453/go-common-file-dialog I don't know what `go` is, but COM is designed to work with all languages. MinGW should work too, you are probably missing the header file or default `WINVER` is wrong. You can use VS's dll files in gcc, you just can't import the library, you have to use the c-interface (this would be last option in this case) You might get a better answer if you ask about one technology.